# External HDD - Detection issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I recently started working on Linux Ubuntu and I just bought an external HDD (Silicon Power Armor A60 2T). 
When plugging the external HDD into my computer (Acer Spin i5), I can hear that the HDD is detected and a red light appears on the HDD. When I open the disk manager, the name of the HDD appears too. However, it does not recognize the size of the HDD nor allows me to access it at all.

Could any of you help me fix this problem so I can use my external hard disk and store in it all my docs?

Thank you in advance

[Attached is a screenshot to illustrate the issue (Gnome + file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CbMM.png)
[Attached is a screenshot of the GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqm5U.png)

Please I'm in urgent need of help, I need my HDD for work. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you check it with GParted? Do you see the disk and any partition?

Comment: No, I checked in the GParted and it doesn't show the HDD nor its partitions.

Comment: That is strange. You mentioned you see the HDD's name in the disk manager. But that is impossible without seeing the disk in GParted. Did you change disk in GParted (top-right part of the screen). By default it shows /dev/sda.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the drive is formatted using exFAT or with [FAT32 with incompatible cluster size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493262/fat32-formatting). Though most Unix distros can use NTFS, FAT, FAT32 and ext*n*, you need to install exFAT file system... [easily done](https://itsfoss.com/mount-exfat/).

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal.
- Type (or copy/paste) `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, if you've not yet enabled outside repositories.
- Type `sudo apt update` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to update the system.
- Type `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install fuse to add exFAT access.

If this does not work, or if you prefer to change the disk file system, perhaps to NTFS (Windows compatible) or ext4, [use the Disk Utilty](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/) to modify the disk. **Caution**: be sure you're modifying the correct drive. You can also change it to "[VFAT32 with a 4096 byte allocation size which is commonly used by Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493262/fat32-formatting)," from Terminal, [by using * mkdosfs*](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mkfs.msdos.8.html):

`sudo mkdosfs /dev/{Disk/Partition} -s 16 -F 32`.

The *caveat* above applies here, yet more so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I had previously formatted the extrenal HDD in a Windows 10 OS to system file NTFS. What should I do in this case for the HDD to be recognized and accessible in my computer?

Comment: That depends on where you want to use it. If it is Linux-only, then ext4. If it is Windows + Linux, you can format it to exFat.